# SSH/SFTP to Centos 7 from Coda

Tags: ssh, centos7, pam

I am running a droplet on DO with Centos 7 - from my mac terminal I can login as root (with password) without any problems.

But if I try the same from Coda (editor) I run into problems.

My audit log file looks like this:

```
Nov 15 21:19:14 ePHIcenter sshd[1932]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=$
Nov 15 21:19:14 ePHIcenter sshd[1932]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "r$
Nov 15 21:19:16 ePHIcenter sshd[1932]: Failed password for root from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 48374 ssh2
Nov 15 21:19:16 ePHIcenter sshd[1932]: Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 11: do_connect error [preauth]
Nov 15 21:19:36 ePHIcenter sshd[1934]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=$
Nov 15 21:19:36 ePHIcenter sshd[1934]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "r$
Nov 15 21:19:38 ePHIcenter sshd[1934]: Failed password for root from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 48357 ssh2
Nov 15 21:19:38 ePHIcenter sshd[1934]: Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 11: do_connect error [preauth]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any special characters in your password, like @, $, or ! ?  It looks like coda isn't handling them correctly.

Try a simpler password first, then I'd recommend using public keys.

http://noscope.com/2012/08/make-your-ssh-keys-work-in-coda-2/